# complexity of set::insert

Tags: c++, stl, set, time-complexity

I have read that insert operation in a set takes only log(n) time. How is that possible?

To insert, first we have find the location in the sorted array where the new element must sit. Using binary search it takes log(n). Then to insert in that location, all the elements succeeding it should be shifted one place to the right. It takes another n time.

My doubt is based on my understanding that set is implemented as an array and elements are stored in sorted order. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: You are assuming that `std::set` is implemented as a sorted array. Why?

Comment: Taken from cppreference: *Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees.*

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Now only I got to know that sets are implemented using red-black tree. Thanks chris

Comment: Well, it should be known to anyone caring about data structures that sets are usually implemented using **trees or hashes, not using arrays**, because of performance... Heck, in Java, you actually have to decide whether you want a `HashSet` or a `TreeSet` (which is a `SortedSet`), and I doubt there is an ArraySet available. (Note that unmodifiable sets *can* efficiently be implemented as a sorted array, using binarySearch - so actually as a sorted tree stored in an array)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Actually, a flat set is, in many cases, more performant than a tree-based set, due to cache locality.

Comment: Accoriding to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/) complexity is logN. If you specify position it is amortized constant, and to insert n elements - n.log (set_size + n)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I can compile my set into a finite automaton (think of regular expressions), at which point it will outperform a flat list. But it's even less general. Once you have larger sets than your cache size, tree and hash sets win when implemented well. The point is, the chances of the tree/hash set performing really bad a low. A flat set may perform well - or be really slow.

Answer (score 57):

`std::set` is commonly implemented as a red-black binary search tree.  Insertion on this data structure has a worst-case of O(log(n)) complexity, as the tree is kept balanced.

Answer (score 1):

Things do not get shifted over when inserting to a set. It is usually not stored as a vector or array, but rather a binary tree. All you do is add a new leaf node, which takes O(1). So in total insertion takes O(log(n))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Intermediry Data Structure Red-Black Tree |||
Inserting 1 Element log(n) time |||
n element nlog(n) time**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).