# Big O Notation - Including Data Structure Costs?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

For the purpose of my question, I'll include a sample problem.

Say we need to iterate through a vector of N Elements and remove duplicates. So, we'd probably use a set right? (Let's use a C++ Set that's a tree)

O(N) cost to iterate through each element - then insert into the Set Data Structure.

My question [Has a log n cost with the Set structure,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776485/complexity-of-setinsert) and we insert N times, is this algorithm O(N log N) or simply O(N)? I was discussing this with a professor, and I'm not sure. The Leetcode/SO/online community seems to disregard data structure costs, but from an academic point of view, N inserts into a red/black tree with log N worst case - This is Log N, N times no?

For clarification - Yes It'd make more sense to use unordered_set, but that doesn't make my question valid.

Comment: "The Leetcode/SO/online community seems to disregard data structure costs" [citation needed]

Comment: Are you sure, wherever this occured, they were not referring to a hashset? Set doesn't imply binary search tree, just because that's the case in C++

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is `O(n * log(n))`. If you have a method like

```
public void foo(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Call a method that is in O(log n)
        someLogNMethod();
    }
}
```

then the method `foo` runs in `O(n * log n)` time.

---

### Example

There are many non-constructed examples. Like computing the **median**-value in an array of integer. Take a look at the following solution to this problem which solves it by **sorting** the array first. Sorting is in `Theta(n log n)` (see [comparison based sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort)).

```
public int median(int[] values) {
    int[] sortedValues = sort(values);

    // Let's ignore special cases (even, empty, ...) for simplicity
    int indexOfMedian = values.length / 2;

    return sortedValues[indexOfMedian];
}
```

Obviously you wouldn't call this `median` method to be in `Theta(1)` though all it does runs in **constant time** (excluding the `sort` method).

However, the problem depends on the `sort` method. You can't solve the problem of finding the *median* of general arrays in `O(1)`. You need to include the `sort` in your analysis. The method thus actually runs in `Theta(n log n + 1)` which is `Theta(n log n)`.

Note that the problem can actually be solved in `Theta(n)` (see [Find median of unsorted array in O(n) time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/find-median-of-unsorted-array-in-on-time)).

Comment: Hem, median, not mean. And fetching the median of a *sorted* array is absolutely Θ(1). [By the way, the median of an unsorted array can be found in Θ(N) operations.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust Uff, `median` of course. Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah, but I didn't state that the array is sorted. The implementation needs to sort it prior. I am referring to the problem of computing the `median` of arrays in general.

Comment: I am referring to your "except the call to sort". [And as said above, a sort is not mandated.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. I edited again, maybe that cleared the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Complexities express the count of some reference operation.

For example, you can very well count the inserts in some black-box structure and enumerate O(N) inserts.

But if you focus on, say, comparisons and you know that an insert costs Log N comparisons on average, the total number of comparisons is O(N Log N).

Now if you are comparing strings of Log N characters, you will count O(N Log²N) character comparisons...